# error [hpm] error occurred while trying to proxy request site

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, ubuntu, proxy

First time doing a project, backend data doesn't come from 3000 ports.  I really don't know what the problem is. I'd really appreciate it if you let me know.

**Springboot TestController**

```java
package com.example.joyit;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/api/test")
    public String text(){
        return "test api";
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```js
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [testStr, setTestStr] =useState('');

  function callback(str){
    setTestStr(str);
  }
  useEffect(
    ()=>{
      axios.get('/api/test')
      .then((Response)=>{callback(Response.data)})
      .catch((Error)=>{console.log(Error)})
    }, []
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        
        api/test =={'>'}
          {testStr}
        
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**setupProxy.js**

```js
const{createProxyMiddleware} = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app){
    app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target:'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
            changeOrigin:true,
        })
    );
};
```

[image]

Backend data is not coming.

I'd really appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `axios` in `reactjs`,its better to use service class for calling apis.

```
class ApiService{
async getData(){
    const response = await axios.get('/api/test')
    return response;
  }
}
```

You can later reuse it in any other components with tryCatch statements.

```
const fetchData = async() => {
       try {
            const response =await apiService.getData()
            setTestStr(response.data)
        } catch (error) {
          toast.error(error.response.data)
        }

}

 useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [])
```

And if you are usinf `SpringBoot` you can use `ResponseEntity` Class to respond the body back.

```
    @GetMapping("/api/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> text(){
        return new ResponseEntity("test api",HttpStatus.Ok);
    }
```

And also if you are using `SpringSecurity`,make sure it has permission to access the method.